# Sum union values

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to sum two values across a UNION. Like:

```
SELECT
       sum(target_value) FROM table
UNION ALL
SELECT 
       sum(target_value) FROM table_2
```

But rather than getting the 2 sum values, I want them to also be summed.

How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using this in a subquery and calculate at the outer query. Ensure you use `UNION ALL` to evade the duplicate check

```
SELECT SUM(a) target_value
FROM
(SELECT
       sum(target_value) a FROM table
UNION ALL
SELECT 
       sum(target_value) a FROM table_2) ;
```

Comment: I also see the union all.  I will address that.  This works perfectly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `WITH` clause to do this:

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT SUM(target_value) as FirstSum 
             FROM table
             UNION
             SELECT 
             SUM(target_value) as FirstSum 
             FROM table_2)

SELECT SUM(FirstSum) AS TotalSum FROM CTE
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see the example below:

```
create table #temp (x int)
create table #temp2 (x2 int)

insert into #temp values (2)
insert into #temp values (3)

insert into #temp2 values (5)
insert into #temp2 values (6)

select t.col1,t.col2,t.col1+t.col2 as Total 
from (
        SELECT (select sum(x) FROM #temp) as col1,
               (select sum(x2) FROM #temp2) as col2
     ) t
```

Comment: why in your example have you added a # to the table names?

Comment: if you put # while creating table, it means the table is a "temprorary" table. You close the query window, the table is gone, no need to drop the table from the database later.